# how to pull the two variables from a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
I have a data with 4 variables  
>>>data  
   var1    var2    var3    var4  
    1       ee     tree     x    
    2       bb     vfgr     y   
    3       aa     skfg     z  
    4       bg     ggff     a
```

how can i bring the var3 and var4 into sampledata?

```
>>>sampledata = data(['var2','var3'])
```

> error:    dataframe is not callable

please help me how to pull the variables that i want?

Expected output:

```
>>>sampledata  
var2    var3  
ee      tree  
bb      vfgr  
aa      skfg  
bg      ggff
```

Comment: wrong brackets... it's `data[index]` not `data(index)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the columns you need to pass a list of the columns of interest to the subscript operator:

```
In [104]:

sampledata = df[['var1','var3']]
sampledata
Out[104]:
   var1  var3
0     1  tree
1     2  vfgr
2     3  skfg
3     4  ggff
```

What you tried to do was to treat the dataframe object as a function which raised your error:

```
In [105]:

df()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-11abb07c39fc> in <module>()
----> 1 df()

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

So in your case the following should work:

```
sampledata = data[['var2','var3']]
```